# How can Maven acquire a dependency from Artifactory that has met a certain criteria?

Tags: maven, artifactory

For a maven build that has a dependency on an internally developed component updated frequently in Artifactory, I'm struggling with understanding a solution for what must be a common use case.

The internal artifact I'm dependent on is built many times per day but not with a -SNAPSHOT pattern. Instead, something like this: 1.0.buildNumber.

Of those various builds for that artifact published to Artifactory, (~ 100 per day), some meet certain testing criteria and are marked with a custom property in artifactory, denoting that they've met that testing criteria, let's call that property "fullyTested". This is determined and annotated after the artifact was initially published, it's simply 'updating' the artifact to add that Artifactory property.

My question is: How do I instruct Maven to acquire the most recently 'fullyTested' artifact? Today the version of the dependency is statically defined as a property inside the pom file, and the dependency section uses that property variable for the 'version' field of the dependency.

There are cumbersome ways to determine this with Artifactory APIs that can be used out of band immediately before the build, and then I can override the statically defined version defined in the property of the pom file with a -D on the maven command line, but there must be a better way.

I doubt my company is going to change how they publish artifacts any time soon, so hoping this can be solved on the client side.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this.  I've seen people do the infamous "-LATEST" dependency which is terrible enough.  This attribute thing seems one giant leap of obfuscation further.  I feel your pain!  The people making these decisions more often than not are too stupid to know they are using the tools all wrong.

Comment: You could use version range for example `<version>[1.0,)</version>`...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using **Matrix Parameters** to specify "fullyTested"-artifacts only in resolution (repository URL).

Link: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution

Comment: I had looked at that, and while I understand how those attributes can get set in Artifactory for those artifacts when deploying, I don't understand what native syntax Maven would support for acquiring artifacts with that constraint on subsequent builds. That's the part that seems missing.